# Change ocean modifier wave direction setting to global coordinates

Tags: drivers, displacement, texture-coordinates, ocean-simulation

The Ocean modifier has a "direction" parameter among the settings.

[image]

Is there a way to make that a Global setting? It is currently "local x" according to the manual.

Alternatively, can it be made to respond to changes in another object? Unfortunately it doesn't accept drivers, but I can use python in the terminal to allocate the rotation value of the camera, for example, to this setting:

[image]

...but it can only be updated manually. Maybe it would work as a scripted expression, but I keep getting "invalid python expression" errors, and I'm unsure where the driver should reside, on the Ocean object or the driving object.